# Sustaining EditText data through activity changes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I can't seem to use data that is in an EditText box.

I have one activity for entering a url and a submit button.

When the user clicks submit, a new activity opens as a WebView and should display the url that
the user typed in the EditText box.

This should be the simplest of tasks but I can't find how to do it anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write below code

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("Url", edittext.getText());
```

And you can fetch this string in NextActivity using

```
  String url = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("Url");
```

Answer (score 0):

when you create the Intent to start the next activity, you will use Intent.putExtra(...) to bundle the url and set the action to VIEW.

see the examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).